# websphere shared library native path not loading

Tags: jvm, websphere-7

I am using `Websphere Application Server v7.0.0.29` version. My objective is to add some native library into Websphere shared library. On adding the native path in a shared library and referencing it to the application , the corresponding paths are updated properly in `AppSrvr/config/cells/CellName/Cluster/library.xml`.

However , I could not see the native library paths I added in the `SystemOut.log` file "J`ava Library Path`" . (Application is not loading the paths ). Also the class loaders are not having it. Even after Referencing . I tried complete shutdown of all `WAS and JVM` process and restarting , but didnt work.

Please suggest how could I proceed ?

Regards,
Chandru

Comment: did you set the argument at the server or cluster level? have you tried this on a plain server instance?

Comment: I have referenced the shared library at cluster level. I am also able to see the same shared library being referenced under AppServer->ClassLoader->Library Reference. But not in in the class loader tree or neitehr in WAS log. However I am able to load the libraries by adding them directly as a variable (java.library.path) under AppServer->JVM->customproperties, But the requirement is that it must load only through shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I missed to update the solution to this issue. It appeared to be a very peculiar issue. I raised a PMR at IBM and it was resolved by hard restarting the Physical server completely after which the native libraries were loaded fine.

My guess is that Some other JVM instance of the same JRE were still running , which might have created the issue.

Anyways if any of you happen to face this issue, hard restarting the server could be a solution to be considered as it resolved in my case.

Regards, 
Chandru

Answer (score 0):

The native library path needs to be added to the class loader that contains the class that is attempting to load the class. For example, if the class that is using the native library is in an application, then the native library path must be added to the application, or if the class is in a WAR, then the native library path must be added to that WAR module. It does not work to add the native library path to the application server class loader if the class is in an EJB, utility JAR, or WAR.

(That said, native library error messages can sometimes be misleading even if the native library path is configured properly. I recommend updating your question to include the full error message.)

Comment: Could you please explain how to add native library path when the referring class is in the war file? I have tried using System.loadlibrary("sharedlibname") of WAS but its not working.

Comment: @AC_1985 It has been too long since I've used WAS (this answer is over 5 years old).  Perhaps it is not possible to do directly; perhaps it requires specifying the native path on a shared library and associating the shared library with the WAR class loader.  If you're not able to figure that out, I suggest opening a new question referencing this answer so that someone more knowledgeable can answer.

Comment: I could make it work in websphere just by placing the dlls in the server lib's native folder path.